# Token Generation with /oauth2/token MS Azure API returns AADSTS50034 error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have tried to use https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/token to get the access token, but i am getting "AADSTS50034: The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the outlook.com directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/token
username:
password:
client_id:
client_secret:
grant_type:password
scope:openid profile
resource:https://graph.microsot.com/directory.read.all
```

I am getting the error as shown below

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50034: The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the outlook.com directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory.\r\nTrace ID: 63e89d55-afa7-4787-b8b0-cdfa605f0f00\r\nCorrelation ID: e4b72b0e-9731-4427-9378-3c38aa6be96a\r\nTimestamp: 2019-06-26 10:24:38Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50034
    ],
    "timestamp": "2019-06-26 10:24:38Z",
    "trace_id": "63e89d55-afa7-4787-b8b0-cdfa605f0f00",
    "correlation_id": "e4b72b0e-9731-4427-9378-3c38aa6be96a"
}
```

Access token must be returned in response, but i am getting user not added to the App error. Please suggest.

Comment: It is very likely you are using "common", not the tenant-specific endpoint. In either case, you cannot use this flow with personal Microsoft accounts.

Comment: I have the same error, how did you manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) flow with users signing in with a personal Microsoft account.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am able to generate the access token for a user which is sourced from Active directory.

Comment: If I generate a new user in AD, it can connects successfully. But this user doesn't have access to drive. It shows the error: "Tenant does not have a SPO license."

Comment: @SubhashiniVinayagam How did you do that, I mean I am also facing the same problem. How did your resolve it? please help me.